# Tensorflow Keras: Is there a difference defining the acitvation function separately for Conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In some examples, I see Conv2d layers defined like so:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# ....

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation="relu"))

# ....
```

....and in others, I see the model defined like this:

````py
```python
import tensorflow as tf

# ....

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

# ....
````

Is there any difference between defining the activation function/layer separately from a Conv2D layer?

Answer (score 1):

Just programming preference. Doing the activation as a layer can be a bit more demonstrative, especially if you're not doing something common like ReLU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random.uniform([1, 100], minval= -1, maxval=1)
init = tf.constant_initializer(np.eye(x.shape[1], x.shape[1]))
dense_baked_relu = keras.layers.Dense(x.shape[1], activation='relu', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=init)
dense_linear = keras.layers.Dense(x.shape[1], activation='linear', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=init)
relu_layer = keras.layers.ReLU()
y0 = dense_baked_relu(x)
y1 = relu_layer(dense_linear(x))
print(y1 - y0)
```

Edit, if you're skeptical about some nuance between Dense vs Conv2D here's the same concept applied to Conv2D.

```
x = tf.random.uniform([1, 100, 100, 1], minval= -1, maxval=1)
sobel = np.zeros((3, 3, 1))
sobel[:, :, 0] = np.array([[1,0,1],[-1,0,-1],[1,0,1]])
init = tf.constant_initializer(sobel)
conv_baked_relu = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, activation='relu', kernel_size=3, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=init)
conv_linear = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, activation='linear', kernel_size=3, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=init)
relu_layer = keras.layers.ReLU()
y0 = conv_baked_relu(x)
y1 = relu_layer(conv_linear(x))
```